# Silex, how to use my class trough whole application

Tags: php, silex

I have a class called ImapMail.

i want to make a instance of that class.

```
$mailbox = new Anthony\ImapMailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $email, $password);
```

and use that instance $mailbox trough my applcication with the same $email and $password witouth creating new instance again.

what is the best practice doing that in silex microframework

greetz

Answer (score 1):

Because your class is not reused by another application you can still share it:

```
$app['imap'] = $app->share(function($app, $email, $password) {
    return new Anthony\ImapMailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $email, $password);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers.html) for the instantiated class.

Comment: what do i put in public function register(Application $app)?

Comment: The class initialization. In your case create the `$mailbox` var and return it.

Comment: like $app['mailbox'] = new self()?

Comment: i have this now and it works but the protected values are not remembered in other pages

    protected $imapPath;
    protected $login;
    protected $password;
    protected $serverEncoding;
    protected $attachmentsDir;


    public function register(Application $app)
        {
            $app['mailbox'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
           
            return new ImapMailbox();

            });
        }